# Autosize row height depending on cell character count in row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to autosize the row height on cells in a row.They are cells made from merged cells and have wrapped text. I need the row to change height to allow all of the text in a cell to be shown. I also need the height of the cell with the most characters in that row to be dominant.

I tried using the target cell to change height on change depending on character count but when modifiying a cell with less characters the row would shrink back down due to the new target character count.

So, for example in a row that has 4 cells: if the 3rd cell has 200 characters and the height changes to 150 from default, modifying the 4th cell with only 20 characters should keep the row the same height since a cell in the row still has 200 characters.

Comment: Might be helpful to show a screenshot of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should post what code you have as a base for the help you're asking for.

Comment: If your cells are not merged then the regular autofit works well. Is there a way you can avoid using merged cells?

Answer (score 0):

For vertically merged cells: You need to temporarily unmerge the cells, use the autofit for the first row, note the height of the row, then remerge the cells and adjust the height as noted.

This works for setting the height of horizontally merged cells: You need to temporarily unmerge the cells, increase the width of the first cell to the total width of the merged cells, use the autofit for the row, then finally reset the width of the first cell and merge the cells again.